# Open root route instead full link in Angular 17 ssr app

Tags: angular, web-config, server-side-rendering, angular17

I use Angular 17 with SSR. I have a problem when go to link for some page in my site.

Example: I want go `to www.my-site/users/user539883` and put this link to the browser.
Instead open `to www.my-site/users/user539883` browser firstly open `www.my-site` home page and in one second then redirect `to www.my-site/users/user539883`. I didn't have this issue with Angular 16.

I think the problem can be related with `web.config`. After deploy to `Azure Web Service` I had the problem with `This resource was removed or delete...` I fixed it with adding `web.config` and then I have this new one problem with load home page firstly.
The code of my `web.config`

```html
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
     </staticContent>

      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```